# Unit test HttpClient that uses credentials in .NET 5

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit, .net-5

I have this in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddHttpClient("ClientUsingCredentials")
        .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
        {
            var credentials = new NetworkCredential("someUsername", "somePassword");
            return new HttpClientHandler()
            {
                // UseDefaultCredentials = true,
                Credentials = credentials
            };
        });
```

Now, my service looks like this:

```
public class WebAppService : IWebAppService
{
    private readonly ILogger<WebAppService> _logger;
    private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory;

    public WebAppService(ILogger<WebAppService> logger, IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _httpClientFactory = httpClientFactory;
    }

    public async Task<WebAppReport> CheckWebSiteWithCredentialsAsync(string someUrlThatNeedsCredentials)
    {
        WebAppReport report = new();

        try
        {
            using (var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("ClientUsingCredentials"))
            {
                var result = await client.GetAsync(someUrlThatNeedsCredentials);

                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    // Do something with the result
                    report.IsCheckSuccessful = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    // Set report fields accordingly
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, $"Something went wrong while checking the website: '{someUrlThatNeedsCredentials}'.");
            // Set report fields accordingly
        }

        return report;
    }
}
```

The `WebAppReport` class:

```
public class WebAppReport
{
    public bool IsCheckSuccessful { get; set; }
    //Some other fields here
}
```

Is there a way to write unit test for this service method that also checks that it passes correct credentials while sending out requests?

**Edit:** I see @Nkosi's answer saying that Unit testing is not possible in this case. So, can you please show an example for doing *integration* test on it?
Should I be creating the service in my test method using `new ServiceCollection()`, add the service in the same way I did in `ConfigureServices` method, set correct `credentials` and so on? Would love to see your example on it.

Thank you!

Comment: Where are the credentials used in the subject under test. If they are not explicitly accessed then there really is no need to add them when mocking for the test

Comment: @Nkosi Thank you for the response. I just edited my question to make it more clear.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to write unit test for this method that also checks that it passes correct credentials while sending out requests?

Short answer: **No**. Not in a **unit test**.

That is because the `ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler` is a framework cross-cutting concern that is only applied by the actual `HttpClientFactory` at run time when creating the actual client that will be used to make the request.

You are basically trying to test that the HttpClientFactory implementation will behave as designed. Microsoft would have tested that before releasing it for use.

For your specific scenario, something like that would ideally need to be done in an **integration test**.

For testing your `WebAppService` you should focus on the logic local to the subject under test.

Comment: Oh I see. can you please show an example for doing *integration* test on it? Should I be creating the service in my test method using `new ServiceCollection()`, add the service in the same way I did in `ConfigureServices` method, set correct `credentials` and so on? Would love to see your example on it. Thank you for your time!